# 'AnyObject' is not a subtype of 'NSObject' in setting name to segment control

Tags: ios, swift, api

I have been working on api integration to my application I am trying to change the of `UISegmentController` from the data in api, the response from the api is working fine and I can take the data using key, While I bind the data to the particular `UiSegmentControl` I am facing error .

```
self.FabricSegmentControl
    .setTitle((((globalConstants.Fabriclist.value(forKey: "PartComponent") as AnyObject)
    .object(at: 0) as AnyObject)
    .value(forKey: "ComponentName") as! AnyObject), forSegmentAt: 0)
```

I have attached the code for your reference. I need to set the tittle for `uisegmentcontroller` dynamically. The error I am facing is :

> 'AnyObject' is not a subtype of 'NSObject'

Comment: May I suggest breaking down your data structure traversal into successive assumptions, using proper guard and replacing all your ! with ?  Might help narrow down the issue.

Comment: ok I will change and update according to your idea .

Comment: This is Swift. Use native types. Most likely the ObjC runtime (bridge casts to `AnyObject`) is not needed at all. And don't use `value(forKey` unless you know what KVC is and you really need it.